# How to release memory when OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Winform OpenFileDialog,everytime I open it,the memory will increase,dispose () and OpenFileDialog = null not working,the memory does not lose. .

how to fix this ??

```
   private void btnLocalPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofdSelectPicture = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofdSelectPicture.Filter = "PicFile|*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif";
        if (ofdSelectPicture.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (showPicture != null)
                showPicture.Dispose();
            showPicture = Image.FromFile(ofdSelectPicture.FileName);
            if (pbShowPicture.Image != null)
                pbShowPicture.Image.Dispose();
            pbShowPicture.Image = showPicture;
            path = ofdSelectPicture.FileName;
            WordTip.Visible = false;
            if (pbShowPicture.Image != null)
                picOK.Enabled = true;
        }
        ofdSelectPicture.Dispose(); //not working
        ofdSelectPicture = null;  //not working
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption? Because gc is not deterministic and won't necessarily release memory back to the OS, only a memory profiler can give you a true picture of whether the references holding the memory allocations are still rooted.

Comment: So, can you tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: Memory:2000k ,when ofdSelectPicture.ShowDialog(); Memory:5000k; I just don't know how to release it ...

Comment: That depends whether you've discovered a memory leak, or if this is normal operation of gc. You need to measure effectively before deciding if you really have a problem. How are you measuring??? Surely the amount of memory in question is negligible? How many file dialogs do you intend to open?

Comment: You should never (have to) call GC.Collect().

Comment: @HenkHolterman uhmm just a newb question, why don't you call `GC.Collect`? :)

Comment: If opening a file dialog causes loading of additional dll s, then this memory will not be released until the appdomain is unloaded

Comment: Are you sure it's not the memory for the `Image` you're seeing? Does the memory consumption keep increasing without limit every time you open a new picture? Or is it only after the first image?

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo - because the GC knows (best) when to Collect(). Calling it is no substitute for proper memory (reference) management.

Comment: 1) GC.Collect() method should never be used in production code, since it interferes with the garbage collection process. 2)Analyzing the application for memory leaks should only be performed using a profiler such as RedGate ANTS Memory Profiler.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Only first time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see what's going on with Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick the "Enable unmanaged debugging" option.  Start your program and select the Output window.  Get the dialog displayed.

You'll now see a list of DLLs getting loaded into your process.  These are shell extensions registered on your machine.  Exactly what you'll get is unpredictable, everybody has their own set of favorite extensions.  Programmers tend to have a lot of them.

Yes, these extension will consume memory in your process.  Just by the fact that these DLLs occupy space in your virtual memory address space.  But also because these DLLs allocate memory for their own use.  And a poorly written one can certainly leak memory.  Beware that the memory allocated by these extensions is always unmanaged memory so be sure you have a good tool that shows you the leak.  Something like TaskMgr.exe isn't good enough.

Two basic things you can do about it.  First is to just ignore it, this problem is specific to your machine and your user won't have the same problem.  You can't fix the leak, you don't have the source code for the extension.  Or you can chase down the troublemaker with the SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.  It shows you what shell extensions are registered and allows you to un-register them by clicking a checkbox.

Comment: So there is no way to fix this ? My boss ask me to fix this ...,it bothers me a lot...

Comment: Is there any way to use OpenFileDialog instead of VS