# Microsoft.win32.SaveFileDialog interferes with memory usage WPF (.Net5)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5, savefiledialog

I have a private method in my MVVM view model that is called when the user presses a button on the view. In this method I want to ask the user to specify a file to save, and then call a static class library to perform some image processing (reading files from disc, doing some minor processing and writting them to an mp4 file using ffmediaToolkit.

```
private void makeMP4()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Media File (*.mp4)|*.mp4";
    saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"D:\temp\mp4output\";
    saveFileDialog.FileName = myImageHandler.SuggestedFileName + ".mp4";

    // If I remove the following line, memory usage is stable at 1GB. If I keep this line
    // memory grows linearly until program terminates.
    _ = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

    // I also tried passing current window handle to ShowDialog (with same outcome):
    //_ = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault());

    MP4Maker mp4Maker = new(myImageHandler);
    mp4Maker.GenerateMP4(@"D:\temp\mp4maker\hardcodedFileName.mp4");
}
```

As explained by the comments in the code above, if I call the ShowDialog method my applicaiton consumes too much memory while processing the mp4 file. But if I omit the call to ShowDialog, the memory usage is stable at about 1GB.

Two suggested solutions I've seen (and reasons they have not worked for me) are:

1. Passing the current window (parent/owner) handle to the ShowDialog method (see my attempt to do this commented out in code above: This didn't change the memory usage.
2. Using system.windows.forms.savefiledialog as an alternative to Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog: I wasn't able to do this because I am using .Net5 (my understanding is that you can't refernce System.windows.forms from a .net5 application?)

Can anybody see why calls to ShowDialog are causing memory leakage and how to prevent it? Thank you.

Comment: Might be due to a misbehaving shell extension, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708773/how-to-release-memory-when-openfiledialog

Comment: Of course you can reference Winforms libraries.

Comment: @BionicCode, well apparently not without modifying the project file to use windows forms. I followed this link to achieve it: https://newbedev.com/how-to-reference-system-windows-forms-in-net-core-3-0-for-wpf-apps , but unfortunately the same apparent memory leak is occurring.

Comment: @KlausGütter, Thanks for the tip. I think the fact that the winforms library produces the same behaviour is consistent with your conclusion. Tracking this down further is taking me some time.

Comment: The Save Dialog is an *Operating System control*. No matter the runtime, in the end you use the OS dialog box. If there was a memory issue people would have noticed in the past 20-30 years. Besides, 1GB memory usage is a **lot** and suggests your application is leaking in one way or another. Perhaps it's keeping a lot of binary data in memory? Inserting lots of items in lists in an inefficient way? Perhaps you've installed a leaky shell extension that tries to process every file when it's displayed in Explorer or a File dialog? How man MP4 files are there?

Comment: In any case, it's impossible to help except to say the problem isn't `ShowDialog`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the generateMP4 function is reading  20 1024x1000 pixel JPGs from zip files and convincing them to make a frame of the MP4. So I don't think 1GB memory is unreasonable. It does this for 38,000 frames, but with no use of showdialog or with the solution (now identified) the memory remains stable at 1GB throughout the 1 hour task. I agree, is not simply a bug in ShowDialog, but clearly an issue at least on my two machines.

Comment: @bbarrett not unless there's a leak. If you reuse buffers for example you shouldn't have to use more than 30-40MB to hold one uncompressed frame at a time. Sure, video compression requires a lot of frames but that doesn't mean they all have to be in memory. You can reuse buffers instead of allocating new ones. You can preallocate `List<>` or `Dictionary<>` instances instead of growing them item by item, which results in double the RAM usage and memory fragmentation

Comment: @bbarrett and if you start using [Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines) your compression method won't even realize the buffers it receives come from multiple files, while buffers. That's what tools like eg ffmpeg do to compress frames into video files *without* caching everything in memory

Comment: @bbarrett you can see the memory usage in real life if you open the [Diagnostic Tools window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/) during debugging. If you see a sawtooth graph, it means you have a lot of orphaned objects that get GC'd periodically. GC is *very* expensive so the best solution is to avoid orphans, eg avoid creating new buffers all the time.  You can use eg [ArrayPool](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/) for example, to resuse buffers from a pool

Comment: @bbarrett if you use MemoryStream a lot, you're allocating buffers. Once again, preallocating the buffer by specifying a `capacity` will reduce reallocations, but won't help you reuse memory. You can also use [Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) to create a memory stream based on reusable buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog` you should try running

`GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`

Which should force .Net to clean up any memory relating to the previous calls before then calling the next routines.

Comment: I don't belife this will help, ijn most cases GC.Collect() does not help to avoid memory issues because the GC is good by itself. if you not tested a answer by yourself it is better to make a recommendation via commend.

Comment: Sorry new to adding comments on this platform. I have tested it so I can confirm it will in this case fix the problem. I agree in principle with what you are saying though.

Comment: @CCQ Thank you for your offline assistance. We confirmed that the problem does not occur if I put the showdialog in the main view's constructor before the initializecomponent(), but it does occur if I move it after initializecomponent(). Very strange, but this lead us to conclude that some garbage collection occurring during initializecomponents is tidying up whatever is leaking memory when the dialog is opened. The use of your suggested GC commands has fixed the problem

Comment: @bbarrett if you have to do this, you have a leak and just covered it up. Perhaps you forget to dispose streams, images or ZipArchive. Or perhaps you allocate new buffers for each file instead of reusing buffers. Or add 38K items to a list one by one instead of preallocating the list with `new List<x>(38000)`. Lists grow by allocating new buffers when they're full, so adding items one by one leads to `log2(N)` allocations and almost double the memory usage. And fragmentation that leads to OutOfMemoryException errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Odd that the memory leak is only exposed when using the dialog. But I get that memory leaks can be fickle like that. Thanks for the many tips for reducing memory load and efficiency.

Comment: @bbarrett they aren't. There's always a reason and Visual Studio allows you to find it. You can take memory snapshots before and after and inspect the difference by object type. The dialog box displays a folder with 38K items which means any shell extensions will run 38K times. If the shell extension is inefficient, or if eg the folder displays thumbnails, you'll get a lot of memory usage. As the dialog box is hosted by your application, the memory used counts against your application as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not wanting to prolong the discourse unnecessarily, but wanted to clarify, the 38K images are contained within 68 zip files, and the dialog has a filetype filter that excludes zip files, so I'm not sure the shell extensions would even see them. Also, related to some of your earlier comments, the 38K images is not a predictable number. User will navigate to their own content with different numbers of images. Thanks again for all of your pointers.

Comment: @bbarrett use Visual Studio's memory window to see what's actually going on. `GC.Collect();` doesn't fix the leak, it deletes the leaked objects. If anything, allocating so much memory wastes CPU. Don't you want to know what kind of objects are getting allocated that take up GBs of RAM?